# Page view controller using CAPSPageMenu controller titles are not displaying according to Screen size in iOS 10?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uistoryboard, uipagecontrol

I am using CAPSPageMenu for page controller, loading two view controllers as a first screen, but it is not displaying controller title array in 6s plus device. it is displaying like this,

[image]

I want to display half the screen as for screen size.

Here is my code i am using ,

```
NSArray *controllerArray = @[jobVC, course];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorWidth: @(1.0),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionUseMenuLikeSegmentedControl: @(YES),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuMargin:@(20.0),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorRoundEdges: @(YES),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectionIndicatorHeight :@(2.0),CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight: @(0.5)
};

_pageMenu = [[CAPSPageMenu alloc] initWithViewControllers:controllerArray frame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height) options:parameters];
_pageMenu.delegate = self;
[self.contentView addSubview:_pageMenu.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your view contollers correctly. Like this way:

Firstly add a property for `CAPSPageMenu` in your base view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic) CAPSPageMenu *pagemenu;
```

Then add following code in the `viewDidLoad` function in your view controller:

```
NSMutableArray *controllerArray = [NSMutableArray array];

// Example view controller creation:
UIViewController *firstController = [UIViewController alloc] initWithNibname:@"YourFirstControllerNibName" bundle:nil];
controller.title = @"YOUR SAMPLE TITLE (eg. SEARCH JOBS)";
[controllerArray addObject:firstControllerName ];

UIViewController *secondController = [UIViewController alloc] initWithNibname:@"YourSecondControllerNibName" bundle:nil];
secondController .title = @"YOUR SAMPLE TITLE (eg. SEARCH COURSE)";
[controllerArray addObject:secondController  ];

//Customize your page menu with parameters:
NSDictionary *parameters = @{CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorWidth: @(1.0),
                         CAPSPageMenuOptionUseMenuLikeSegmentedControl: @(YES), 
                //... and more...
                             };
// Initialize page menu
_pageMenu = [[CAPSPageMenu alloc] initWithViewControllers:controllerArray frame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) options:parameters];

//Optional delegate
_pageMenu.delegate = self;

// Lastly add page menu as subview of base view controller view
[self.view addSubview:_pageMenu.view];
```

You can also use these delegate functions below for control move actions if you want:

```
- (void)willMoveToPage:(UIViewController *)controller index:(NSInteger)index {}

- (void)didMoveToPage:(UIViewController *)controller index:(NSInteger)index {}
```

Comment: i tried like above but still not working on iPhone 7

Comment: Check your _CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuMargin_ and your other parameters. Please firstly try it with default parameters. Your custom parameters may be causing the confusion.

Comment: from above image i am loading with default parameters only. in 5s working good but at 7s it is not working.